Tag ordering - should the OP or the system decide?
I've just submitted a question and I put the tags that I had chosen in a particular order but looking at my question after posting, the system has changed the order of the tags.
The system appears to have opted for listing the tags in order of the tag's popularity, whereas I originally listed them in the order of what I felt was of most relevance.
I'm just wondering why the system can't just let us choose our own ordering?
It's the OP's question, so let the OP decide (feature request)!

I don't believe this can be changed on a per-site basis, so I'll address it from a network-wide point of view:
A previous feature request for this can be found at:
Do not order tags on questions based popularity and keep them in order specified by asker/editor.
The request was declined in June 2012 by Shog9. His answer is reproduced below for convenience:

Tags exist to categorize the questions they're attached to. They're independent of each other, and may be merged, renamed, or
removed without regard to their order or importance on any particular
question.
Titles exist to introduce and summarize the questions they're attached to. Each title exists independently from all other titles,
and can be edited and refined by the author or any competent editor.
If server and java represent topics your question pertains
to, then make sure they're included in the tags.
If the terms "server" and "java" are both critical to understanding
your problem, then make sure they're in the title. But also make sure
the title is a clear statement of your problem. If this means
wording it such that "server" comes before "java", then so be it.


Hmmm... separation of concerns. Thanks - I see the point!
